Troubleshooting Laravel 9 and Ajax form data not saving to database
I cannot save the form data using Laravel 9 and Ajax. The city_name, longitude, and latitude come from the JSON file, so when I choose a city, its longitude and latitude get dynamically filled up. I manually enter the address and save the form, but an error pops up. From the controllers, when I used the function dd($workplaces), nothing happened, and from the JavaScript, the console.log(data) gives an empty data[] like below:
Look here form data = 
FormData(6) {
  _token → "SnoXgjegU7tuk3HdoWUoj88egv2evUyLDZnGroC5",
  city_name → "Bafoussam",
  address → "<p>qwerty</p>",
  latitude → "5.4667",
  longitude → "10.4167",
  workplaces_id → "" 
}
workplace:800:17

Server response: 
Object {
  draw: 0,
  recordsTotal: 0,
  recordsFiltered: 0,
  data: []
}
workplace:809:25

That tells me an error isn't listed in the log file or the browser console. I would appreciate any help in solving the issue. My initial code is below.
Controllers
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $workplaces_id = $request->workplaces_id;
    // dd($workplaces_id);

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        if ($workplaces_id != '') {
            # update case
            return $this->update($request, $workplaces_id);
        } else {
            # insert case
            $validator = $request->validated();
            // dd($validator);
            try {
                DB::beginTransaction();
                $workplaces = Workplace::create(
                    [
                        'city_name' => $validator['city_name'],
                        'address' => $validator['address'],
                        'longitude' => $validator['longitude'],
                        'latitude' => $validator['latitude'],
                        'created_by' => \Auth::user()->id
                    ]
                );
                DB::commit();
                dd($workplaces);
                return Response()->json(
                    [
                        'success' => true,
                        'data' => $workplaces,
                        'message' => trans('hrprofile::Workplace.job_pos_create')
                    ]
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                DB::rollback();
                Log::error($e->getMessage()); 
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
            }
        }
    }
}

JavaScript
// STORING DATA FORM INTO THE DATABASE
$('#WorkplaceForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var addresses = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    $('#address').val(addresses);
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    console.log('Look here form data =', formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('workplace.store') }}",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: (data) => {
            console.log('Server response:', data);
            if (data.success) {
                $("#workplace-modal").modal('hide');
                toastr.success(data.message);
                var oTable = $('#workplace-datatable').dataTable();
                oTable.fnDraw(false);
                $("#btn-save").html("{{ __('formular.save') }}");
                $("#btn-save").attr("disabled", false)
            } else {
                toastr.error(data.message);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            toastr.error(data.message);
        }
    });
});

// DROPDOWN FOR ALL CITIES DYNAMICALLY POPULATE LATITUDE & LONGITUDE
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('/assets/json/cm.json', function(data) {
        // console.log('Data here = ', data); 
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            // Improved option creation
            $('#city_name').append($('<option>').text(value.city).val(value.city));
        });

        $('#city_name').change(function() {
            var selectedCityId = $(this).val();
            var cityData = null;

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                if (value.city == selectedCityId) { // Use strict comparison (===)
                    cityData = value;
                    return false; // Exit the loop after finding the match
                }
            });

            if (cityData) {
                $('#latitude').val(cityData.lat);
                $('#longitude').val(cityData.lng);
            } else {
                $('#latitude').val('');
                $('#longitude').val('');
            }
        });
    });
});

Form view
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0)" id="WorkplaceForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{-- WORPLACE NAME --}}
        <div class="row">
            <div id="additional_department input hidden"></div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="city_name" class="control-label LBL">
                    <span class="text-danger">*</span>{{ __('hrprofile::workplace.wp_name') }}          
                </label>

                <select name="city_name" class="form-select selectpicker" id="city_name" data-width="100%" data-live-search="true" required="">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{-- ADDRESS --}}

        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="address" class="control-label">
                    <span class="text-danger"></span>{{ __('hrprofile::workplace.wp_address') }}
                </label>
                <textarea id="address" rows="5" name="address" class="tinymce" required=""></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{-- LONGITUDE | LATITUDE --}}
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <label for="latitude" class="control-label LBL">
                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                    {{ __('hrprofile::workplace.wp_latitude') }}&nbsp;&#xb0;
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" class="form-control " value="" required="" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <label for="longitude" class="control-label LBL">
                    <span class="text-danger"</span>
                    {{ __('hrprofile::workplace.wp_longitude') }}&nbsp;&#xb0;
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" class="form-control " value="" required="" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        {!! Form::hidden('workplaces_id', '', ['id' => 'workplaces_id']) !!}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btn-save">{{ __('hrprofile::workplace.btn_save') }}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" data-bs-dismiss="modal">{{ __('hrprofile::workplace.btn_close') }}</button>
    </div>
</form>

I tried to change the controllers like the one below but I am still facing the same issue.
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $request->validate([
        'city_name' => 'required',
        'address' => 'nullable', // Update based on your requirement
        'latitude' => 'required',
        'longitude' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $workplaces = Workplace::create([
            'city_name' => $validator['city_name'],
            'address' => $validator['address'],
            'longitude' => $validator['longitude'],
            'latitude' => $validator['latitude'],
            'created_by' => Auth::id(),
        ]);
        DB::commit();

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $workplaces,
            'message' => trans('hrprofile::Workplace.job_pos_create'),
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'An error occurred while saving data.',
        ]);
    }
}


There are a few typos in the methods. Response()->json(...) should be response()->json(...). DB::rollback() should be DB::rollBack(). You might encounter problems later on if you don't correct those.

If you implement livewire in your code it would be so much cleaner and easier to write without the need for all the javascript.

your server response looks like a datatable response, make sure you are posting to the correct controller/method
